# slow deployments when using Solana CLI 1.17.x

Tags: deploy

When I deployed mainnet using Solana 1.17.17, it was very slow and could not be successful

> rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)
> solana-cli 1.17.17 (src:27a43800; feat:1337574167, client:SolanaLabs)

output

```
⠤   9.5% | Sending 48/199 transactions              [block height 224347049; re-sign in 0 blocks]
```

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm having this problem as well.